# Idiomatic loop and break condition

Tags: c#

I am calling a C library via P/Invoke. That library needs to be called in sucession with an increasing `unsigned int`, and returns a pointer. That pointer is then mapped to a managed type, until it returns a `NULL` pointer.

In C, the idiomatic way to write it, is probably `for(i=0;;i++)`, but what is the most idiomatic way to write it in C#?

Currently it is using a `do {} while` loop, as in my opinion, this is the clearest way to show that this loop will repeat until `newPort` is `null`.

```
static IEnumerable<Port> GetPorts ()
{       
    List<Port> ports = new List<Port>();
    uint i = 0;
    Port newPort;
    do {
        // This calls an C library, and maps the returned pointer
        // to the Port class
        newPort = GetPortData (i);
        if (newPort != null){
            ports.Add (newPort);
        }
        i++;
    } while(newPort != null);
    return ports;
}
```

On the other hand, the variables `i` and `newPort` are only used inside the loop, so using `for` would be another solution, but it does not clearly show the breaking condition.

```
    for (uint i = 0; ; i++) {
        Port newPort = GetPortData (i);
        if (newPort == null) {
            break;
        }
        ports.Add (newPort);
    }
```

Which version should I use?

Comment: BTW, this method might be a good candidate for `yield return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the for loop can show the "breaking condition" like this:

```
for (uint i = 0; (newPort = GetPortData(i)) != null; i++) {
    ports.Add (newPort);
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, an expression should be almost always used for its value or for its side effects, but not both.

Comment: I updated the answer. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Not sure if I'm a fan of calling GetPortData twice.  What happens if that method is expensive???